# Complex primary key and constraint error in EF CodeFirst

Tags: sql-server, azure, annotations, ef-code-first

I have a complex primary key in this table defined as follows

```
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int SymbolId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public SymbolType SymbolType { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3), DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

I can add data to the table, the problem is I'm testing by adding data for the same SymbolId each time and not only is that SymbolId not what is showing up in the column, it appears to be an auto-increment column when I specified it to be of type DatabaseGeneratedOption.None. The actual SymbolId is 10 and that is what should be in the SymbolId column for each entry.

[image]

Here is what the table looks like in SQL Azure

[image]

If someone could enlighten me on where my problem lies it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce it on azure but could not.
Things are working for me with the similar set of schema, here is my [schema and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFj8X.png)

Answer (score -3):

You have problem in the database design.

There is no point to make one of the composite keys as Auto Increament.

Composite keys should not be Auto Increament.

Comment: The OP is asking *why* the field ended up being an IDENTITY, even though it's marked `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`. The OP never tried to create a composite index with an IDENTITY field

Comment: The composite key, never was intended to be an identity, auto incremented field, thus the post.